# classpath resources issues in EAR with multiple wars

Tags: ear

We have a application with Single EAR and Multiple WARs  we are able to reslove common class issues between WARs , by placing them in respective WEB-INF/lib folder, 
But when it comes to resources , we have resources in classpath ( e.g abc.xml), which is required for WARs in the ear. but content of abc.xml will be differnt for each WAR.
we cannot keep the abc.xml inside WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes to load it to WAR classloader,  because of environment specific abc.xml .
and also i cannot keep abc.xml  with different name in the classpath too, as it is been used by thirdparty jars which loads this abc.xml using classpath context as show below

String[] paths = {abc.xml} ;
 ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(paths);

is there a way to load this resource into classpath of WAR . ???
bottom line question is , can we set up different classpath for WARs in a EAR ??
Any inputs are highly appreciated .

Thanks
kambi